# pkcs11 exception parsing configuration: Unexpected value Token['(']

Tags: java, java-8, pkcs#11

I know this is not a new problem (see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8023745 ), but I was hoping someone would have a good workaround we could roll out.

We are deploying an application, which is using pkcs11 and have encountered a problem with parsing config, which is located in "Program Files (x86)". What we're getting is:

sun.security.pkcs11.ConfigurationException: Unexpected value Token['('], line 2

In the dev environment, moving the location to a "clean" path solves the problem, so the issue is definitely the (x86).

What would be a good workaround, with, hopefully, minimum trouble to the end user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the best solution was to copy the file to another location, with a "valid" path, using FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(), from org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils .

Answer (score 4):

I found a simple workaround for this problem in Windows. In my case I'm trying to load the nss native libraries from Mozilla 32 bits installation directory. If I configure the path this way:

```
name = NSS
library = C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\softokn3.dll
```

I get the `Unexpected value Token['(']` exception. If instead I trying to add `"` to enclose the library path:

```
name = NSS
library = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\softokn3.dll"
```

Then the error change and I get:

```
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.ConfigurationException: Absolute path required for library value: C:Program Files (x86)Mozilla Firefoxsoftokn3.dll
```

So seems that `"` bypass the parenthesis problem however seems that produce that `file.separator` is lost, so my last attempt was using `"` and "escaping" `file.separator` (simply applying `replace("\\","\\\\")` to the path before putting in the config):

```
name = NSS
library = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\softokn3.dll"
```

This way the library is correctly loaded. I test it for java 8 update 141.